# Loop counter to get factorial

Tags: python, loops, factorial

I have been given the following Pseudocode snippet

```
Function number_function()
Initialise variables factorial, number
Initialise Boolean valid to false
Loop while not valid
    Display “Please enter a positive integer greater than 0”
    Input number
    If number contains numeric characters
        Convert number to integer
        If number is a positive integer
            Set valid to true
        End if
    End if
End loop
Loop for counter from number to 1
    Calculate factorial = factorial x count
    If count is not 1
        Print count and format with multiply
    Else
        Print count and format with equals
    End if
End loop
Print factorial
End function
```

I have written this section myself however I am not sure what it means and how to do the loop for counter from number to 1 could anyone help please?

my code so far

```
def number_function():
    factorial = 0
    count = 1
    number = 0
    valid = False

    while valid != True:
        number = input("Please Enter a positive integer greater than 0 ")    
        if number.isnumeric():
            number = int(number)
            if number >= 0:
                valid = True
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  I would encourage you to keep reading through any Python tutorials or textbooks you're learning from.  It seems you already learned about `while` loops so you will also probably soon learn about `for` loops and `range` as well.  You could also use a while loop and decrement `number` until it equals 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the factorial and print each step of the calculs.
I understand it this way :

```
def number_function():
    factorial = 0
    count = 1
    number = 0

    valid = False

    while valid != True:
        number = input("Please Enter a positive integer greater than 0 ")
        if number.isnumeric():
            number = int(number)
            if number >= 0:
                valid = True

    count = number

    factorial = 1
    while count >= 1:
        factorial = factorial * count
        if count != 1:
            print (count, "*")
        else:
            print (count, "=")
        count -= 1

    print (factorial)


number_function()
```

Example output is:

```
Please Enter a positive integer greater than 0 3
3 *
2 *
1 =
6
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, it looks so easy but for some reason I couldn't get my head around it

Answer (score 0):

you would want to do something like this:

you will not need a count variable, because your number will be your counter.
i added the print lines at strategic points, so you can follow, what the program does.
they are not neccessary and you can delete them afterwards.

```
while (number > 0):       ## looping while number not reached 0
    factorial = factorial * number
    print (factorial)
    number = number - 1   ## diminish counter variable
    print (number)
print (factorial)
```

this will provide your loop. in its header it will test on the condition and then do your factorial equation, then diminish your number to be multiplied again, but smaller until it reaches zero.

i don't quite understand, what is meant by the rest, maybe my english skills fail me. ;)